# Issue renaming two columns in a CSV file instead of one

Tags: c#, csv

I need to be able to rename the column in a spreadsheet from 'idn_prod' to 'idn_prod1', but there are two columns with this name.

I have tried implementing code from similar posts, but I've only been able to update both columns. Below you'll find the code I have that just renames both columns.

```
//locate and edit column in csv
string file1 = @"C:\Users\username\Documents\AppDevProjects\import.csv";
string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(file1);

System.IO.StreamWriter sw = new System.IO.StreamWriter(file1);
foreach(string s in lines)
{
    sw.WriteLine(s.Replace("idn_prod", "idn_prod1"));
}
```

I expect only the 2nd column to be renamed, but the actual output is that both are renamed.
Here are the first couple rows of the CSV:
[image]

Comment: If each line corresponds to a row in the spreadsheet, isn't this not only operating on the header (that names the columns), but also the data rows too?

Comment: We need to see a few rows of import.csv.

Comment: Sure thing. I should have included that initially, @Dour High Arch.
I'll get that added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I'm assuming that you only need to update the column header, the actual rows need not be updated.**

```
            var file1 = @"test.csv";
            var lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(file1);

            var columnHeaders = lines[0];
            var textToReplace = "idn_prod";
            var newText = "idn_prod1";

            var indexToReplace = columnHeaders
                .LastIndexOf("idn_prod");//LastIndex ensures that you pick the second idn_prod
            columnHeaders = columnHeaders
                .Remove(indexToReplace,textToReplace.Length)
                .Insert(indexToReplace, newText);//I'm removing the second idn_prod and replacing it with the updated value.

            using (System.IO.StreamWriter sw = new System.IO.StreamWriter(file1))
            {
                sw.WriteLine(columnHeaders);

                foreach (var str in lines.Skip(1))
                {
                    sw.WriteLine(str);
                }

                sw.Flush();
            }
```

Comment: After testing the solutions provided I did decide to implement yours, @Rakesh. Thank you for your help! :D

Answer (score 1):

Replace foreach(string s in lines) loop with

for loop and get the lines count and rename only the 2nd column.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the only way to handle this properly is to crack the header line (first string that has column names) into individual parts, separated by commas or tabs or whatever, and run through the columns one at a time yourself.

Your loop would consider the *first* line from the file, use the `Split` function on the delimiter, and look for the column you're interested in:

```
bool headerSeen = false;

foreach (string s in lines)
{
    if (!headerSeen)
    {
        // special: this is the header
        string [] parts = s.Split("\t");

        for (int i = 0; i < parts.Length; i++)
        {
            if (parts[i] == "idn_prod")
            {  
                // only fix the *first* one seen
                parts[i] = "idn_prod1";
                break;
            }
        }
        sw.WriteLine( string.Join("\t", parts));

        headerSeen = true;
    }
    else
    {
        sw.WriteLine( s );
    }
}
```

The only reason this is even remotely possible is that it's the header and not the individual lines; headers tend to be more predictable in format, and you worry less about quoting and fields that contain the delimiter, etc.

Trying this on the individual data lines will rarely work reliably: if your delimiter is a comma, what happens if an individual field contains a comma? Then you have to worry about quoting, and this enters all kinds of fun.

For doing any real CSV work in C#, it's really worth looking into a package that specializes in this, and I've been thrilled with [CsvHelper](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/) from Josh Close. Highly recommended.

Comment: Thank you Steve! Your answer and the ones below were very helpful. I am now good to go for this. I'll be sure to check out CsvHelper too.